# Change spacing between lines with tags made with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a following script with `tag` command:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\newcommand{\tag}[1]{%
{
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=black!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
  }
}

\newcommand{\divider}{\textcolor{black!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip}

\begin{document}

\divider
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\divider

\end{document}
```

and it's output:

[image: multiple usage of define command]

I want to increase vertical spacing between tags but do not increase spacing between tags and a divider.

I've tried to achieve that with the following examples but those weren't meeting the second requirement about not changing the spacing between tags and a divider:

```latex
\divider
{ \setstretch{2}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}

}
\divider
```

```
\divider
\begin{spacing}{2}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\end{spacing}
\divider
```

Check examples: https://www.overleaf.com/read/bcfqkznypjbn

Comment: Please be so kind and extend /merge your code fragment to an MWE (Minimal Working example). Link can be dead after while ...

Answer (score 2):

Do you want something like this?

[image: changing some spacing]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{dashrule}

\newcommand{\tag}[1]{%
  \tikz[baseline]\node[anchor=base,draw=black!30,rounded corners,inner xsep=1ex,inner ysep =0.75ex, text height=1.5ex,text depth=.25ex]{#1};
}

\newcommand{\divider}{\par\noindent\textcolor{black!30}{\hdashrule{\linewidth}{0.6pt}{0.5ex}}\medskip\par\noindent}

\begin{document}

\divider
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\divider

\divider
{\setstretch{2}%
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}
\tag{Lorem}
\tag{Ipsum}
\tag{Dolor}\par}
\divider
\divider

\end{document}
```

Comment: Almost, need to get rid of the increased spacing between the upper divider and tags.

Comment: @WojciechKo You can use something like `\vspace*{-2\baselineskip}\par\noindent\setstretch{2}` in place of `\setstretch{2}`. Is that what you want?